# How to find redirect URL from initial URL with Python request.get?

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, python-requests

This [link address](https://rrcsearch3.neubus.com/esd3-rrc/api.php?function=GetAttachment&profile=15&id=kNAMejO3OhA.&docid=_fmqnOHMHZo.) is embedded in HTML from a page that is displayed before the final (redirected) page [here](https://rrcsearch3.neubus.com/rrcdisplay/4217733340-L_%26_J_LEE_UNIT_1H_MDRLT_GAM.s_6c8dd49279da00998f0879b9917ec8a2.las). Using `request.get` on the link address only results in `.text` or `.content` displaying FAIL - even with `allow_redirects=True`.

I want to somehow extract/find the redirected address without actually going to the final page using only the initial link address. If this is possible, how might I do this?

Comment: share the original url and what you are putting into the search query. (I'm assuming your trying to get data through https://rrcsearch3.neubus.com/esd3-rrc/

Comment: You must start here: https://rrcsearch3.neubus.com/esd3-rrc/index.php?_module_=esd&_action_=keysearch&profile=15. Then - for this example - enter 17733351 in the 'API Number Field', press 'SEARCH' and proceed to select/click the FIRST 'Actions' button - this will bring you to what I refer to as initial link address (see HTML)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your initial [initial link](https://rrcsearch3.neubus.com/esd3-rrc/api.php?function=GetAttachment&profile=15&id=kNAMejO3OhA.&docid=_fmqnOHMHZo.) Does not perform a redirect. You can verify by using the network tab in chrome developer tools and looking at the requests there.

To verify in python do the following:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://initial-link.com")
# notice that response.history is an empty list indicating that 
# no redirects took place
response.history
```